# "Let's go go-karting" or "let's do go-karting"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please which sentence sounds more natural?

> Let's **go go-karting** this weekend.
>
> Let's **do go-karting** this weekend.

If neither is natural, what would a natural way to say that?

Comment: You confuse the issue by having an example activity that starts with ***go-***. Not that native speakers would normally even notice the repetition after ***Let's go...***, but non-native speakers might be distracted by it. So far as "idiomatric choices" are concerned, it would be exactly the same question if you'd asked about *Let's **go / do swimming***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine.  These are only two of several hundred ways to express similar ideas.  If you need to "go" somewhere then "go go-karting" would seem an obvious choice. But How about:

> Shall we visit the go-kart track?
>   What about go-karting this weekend?
>   We could visit Cranley Park [where they have go-karts].